# Does the synchronization of metronomes on a moving platform imply force fields on moving bodies are synchronized?

Tags: classical-mechanics

For example, binary stars are known to have powerful gravitational and electromagnetic fields.   Based on the experiment below, can we assume force fields pulsate like metronomes with different frequencies such that they will synchronize when the body moves through spacetime or some platform which is allowed to move.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aaxw4zbULMs

Answer (score 1):

No, we can't. the metronomes on a flexible platform self-synchronize because as they swing, they exert cyclic forces on the platform, which then exerts a very gentle cyclic force on all the metronome mechanisms. cyclic forces on the platform that are out-of-phase get cancelled, and the in-phase ones add- and after a while a couple of metronomes fall into step and their forces add and cancel other metronome forces that are out-of-phase, and so on. after a while, all the metronomes are in sync.

Comment: The experiment is a model which describes what happens when two different frequencies are coupled in the same space.   Other examples can be used as well.  Vibrating atoms at different temperatures will reach an equilibrium temperature or obtain a common frequency when confined to a common space.  Gravitational and electromagnetic forces are harmonic in nature and in the case mentioned are confined to the same space.  The atoms in the thermodynamic case are not swinging but vibrating in all directions to produce the same effect.